# How to get rid of value error showing could not convert string to float in python

Tags: python, jupyter

I was running the following code

```
lr=LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(lr.coef_)
```

But I was getting error like
Value Error: could not convert string to float: '20140527T000000'

How can I solve this?

Comment: Get rid of that string :)  or just don't try to do numeric calculations with that data.  That strings looks like a date with time.  That needs special parsing.

Answer (score 4):

It's look like you tried to convert a string that does not contain a float number to a float. If the python string is not formatted as a floating point number, you could not convert string to float.
Try to find which column is throwing this error and review the column to find the outliers. If the column only contains numerical and null values, then your code will run without the given error